# Opengaph Object at URLmyurl is invalid because the configured 'og:type' of ':mycustomobject' is invalid

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have 3 apps hosted on the same domain. Each app is a different game. I simply use a different  carnevas url www.mywebsite.fr/fb/game.php?gameid={1-2-3}

To test opengraph I have created 2 custom open graph actions : Win and Play that are connected to the object Game

For the first app ok no problem actions and stories are correctly published.
The url for the object Game is  www.mywebsite.fr/fb/opengraph.php?gameid=1
and I call it like this :

```
try{
    $response = $facebook->api(
     'me/myappname:play',
      'POST',
      array(
        'game' => 'www.mywebsite.fr/fb/opengraph.php?gameid=1'
      )
    );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
```

Now I try do do exactly the same for the 2 other apps but I get :

Exception: Object at URL 'https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/' is invalid because the configured 'og:type' of ':game' is invalid.

The url for the object game are www.mywebsite.fr/fb/opengraph.php?gameid=2 and www.mywebsite.fr/fb/opengraph.php?gameid=3

I passed the object urls into the debug tool and everything is fine, response code 206 all properties and opengraph info are corrects.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Since the exception mentions the URL `https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/`, I suspect calling the URL where your app is actually hosted automatically redirects to Facebook?

Comment: Yes it is, in case somebody directly call www.mywebsite.fr/fb/opengraph.php?gameid=1 he is redirected on https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/ (the process worked perfectly for the first app)